# How to truncate text with screen size using ellipses

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/bootstrap-yytzde?file=app/app.component.html) and the [Stackblitz Url](https://bootstrap-yytzde.stackblitz.io) that has 2 bootstrap cards inside a page layout with columns.

**Problem** - With the Name (.card-title) of the card being greater than 11 characters longs (max 15), when I shrink the screen between 768px-1200px the name at the top of the card squishes the star/rating down to the next line.

**Question** - Is there a way to truncate the name (ex. AnneMariesPlace) between 768px-1200px with ellipses, so that the star/rating remains on the same line?
ex. AnneMari...
This would mean the max length would be 8 plus the ellipses (3 chars)

Can it be done with pure CSS using?
FYI - I tried a couple of things with text-overflow: ellipsis; and white-space: nowrap;
but I didn't have much luck.

Here is the code I'm using

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container my-3 my-xl-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      something here
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-9">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="mb-4">
          </div>

          <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2">
            <div class="col mb-4">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="row no-gutters">
                  <div class="col-md-5">
                    <img class="yogaband-img img-fluid w-100" style="object-fit: cover; object-position: center; min-height: 100%;" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/k9dapp/image/upload/c_scale,w_1450,h_1450/f_auto/v1569538700/mainpage/iStock-860080282_bkhfsu.jpg" alt="yogaband">
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-md-7">
                    <div class="card-body py-1">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                          <b class="card-title d-inline">AnneMariesPlace</b>
                          <span class="float-right center-star">
                          &#9733;3.43
                        </span>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                          <span>Access</span>
                          <span class="float-right">Private</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12">
                          <span>Max Size</span>
                          <span class="float-right">10</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12">
                          <span>Events</span>
                          <span class="float-right">323</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12">
                          <span>Type</span>
                          <span class="float-right">Park</span>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col mb-4">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="row no-gutters">
                  <div class="col-md-5">
                    <img class="yogaband-img img-fluid w-100" style="object-fit: cover; object-position: center; min-height: 100%;" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/k9dapp/image/upload/c_scale,w_1450,h_1450/f_auto/v1569538700/mainpage/iStock-860080282_bkhfsu.jpg" alt="yogaband">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-7">
                    <div class="card-body py-1">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                          <b class="card-title d-inline">AnneiMaries</b>
                          <span class="float-right center-star">
                          &#9733;3.43
                        </span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                          <span>Access</span>
                          <span class="float-right">Private</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12">
                          <span>Max Size</span>
                          <span class="float-right">10</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12">
                          <span>Events</span>
                          <span class="float-right">323</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12">
                          <span>Type</span>
                          <span class="float-right">Park</span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: `text-overflow: ellipses;` does this. [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow)

Comment: I tried. Simply putting an ellipses with text-overflow doesn't do anything.

Comment: Holy [divitis](https://www.tyssendesign.com.au/articles/faqs/what-is-divitis/), Batman!

Comment: I agree. This page was built some time ago and I haven't had to time to go back to refactor. Plus it was just thrown into a Stackblitz to get it working to demonstrate what I'm trying to do and what I currently have

Comment: Solutions don't go in your question. A user with your rep should know that. Post a proper answer and accept it, please.

Answer (score 0):

To make ellipsis work you need conditions. First, the element must NOT be `inline`. Yours it is even with an `!important` condition (which I don't know why you set it), second it needs a `width` set (it does not matter if percent or fixed) and last, it needs `overflow:hidden` and `white-space:nowrap` (so the content won't ever take a second line).

Basically, and based on your example, you need this:

```
.d-inline {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: calc(100% - 44px);
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Unfortunately, it looks like your "score" will never get more width space than 44px. Use a bit more to feel safe just in case (browser zooming and such.)

Comment: It's a _really_ bad idea to muck with [core Bootstrap utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/display/) like that. If anything, create a new class, but it's better to just use the proper class.

Comment: I'm front end. I hate boostrap. I would nuke bootstrap headquarter if I could. In a big project I could use just 1000 css lines and 100 javascript lines and replace all the bootstrap shit... while making the web look as the client want (marketing agency design... sadly often not mine). I also hate SCSS, Sass and others, but I can't complain as much... no much weapons against but maybe, maybe... lazyness to learn (which I know it should be a must... but over 50 and tired) .

Comment: So... you can't change your answer so that it doesn't muck about with well-defined third-party classes? Don't get me wrong; more power to you that you get to play in perfect pristine lands unpopulated by third-party platforms, but the rest of the world does.

Comment: Here's what I did for brut force workaround to what I already have, I made 2 different elements where one has the truncated text the other full text and they get hidden on display sizes. I'll post my solution above as an EDIT

Comment: Seems like you're in the wrong profession. Those things you hate so much are fantastic tools (in the right circumstances) for those of us who actually like our jobs. (FWIW, I'm almost 50.)